# Android studio 3 - java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8

Getting following errors in android studio 3 (latest release).

Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs for details.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs for details.

Comment: did you changed VM Options? try deleting `.android` and `.AndroidStudio3.0` folder from c:\users\username\ and restart

Comment: I am running on ubuntu and not on vm.